# Module is not working on Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, module

[image: Here is how my module structure looks]

**Hello.php**

app/code/Magento/Hello/Block/Hello.php

```
namespace Magento\Hello\Block;
class Hello extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
}
```

**Index.php**

```
namespace Magento\Hello\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**routes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="hello" frontName="hello">
        <module name="Magento_Hello" />
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

**module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
     <module name="Magento_Hello" schema_version="0.0.1" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
  </config>
```

**hello_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Hello\Block\Hello" name="hello" template="Magento_Hello::success.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

success.phtml

```
<?php echo ‘Successful! This is a simple module in Magento 2.0′; ?>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Test_HW',
        __DIR__
    );
```

I have added the  *`'Magento_Hello' => 1`* to the **etc/config.php**.

I am running Magento 2 on localhost.

Comment: I am wondering how you get answer. have you check your registration.php is correct? your registration.php should like @Rajkumar .E  answer.

Comment: @BilalUsean I fixed it and now the module is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

using cmd.

This command enable module in your system and one entry are generated under **setup_module** table.

Directly you can't generate entry inside **`app/etc/config.php`** file.

Remove var folder and try again.

Comment: tun **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** then i run **php bin/magento setup:di:compile** and now i have errors after running that command

Comment: which error are generate plz show that

Comment: Which version you've got of Magento 2? In the last update they fix the setup:di:compile , if you have previous version, try to use setup:di:compile:multi-tenant

Comment: I had the php memory error but i fixed it. so the command is run successfully. everything is successfully done but still i cant see the module.

Comment: have you remove var folder from root

Comment: do i have to delete \htdocs\magento\var folder/contents?

Comment: yes whole var folder

Comment: so i delete the var folder, then i directly check **http://127.0.0.1/magento/hello/Index/Index** or do i have to run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command again?

Comment: you can run command and check again

Comment: still not working.

Comment: any error are generated inside var/log folder?

Comment: no there is no error there

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to create module online using **"Magento 2 Module Creator | CedCommerce"** . you need to complete 2-3 basic and simple steps then you can download and install your plugin to your website by following steps :

1. Unzip the downloaded module and paste into the "your_project/app/code/your downloded module
2. sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/*
4. sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
5. sudo php bin /magento cache:clean
6. sudo chmod 777 var -R
7. sudo chmod 777 pub -R

After completing these steps you will find your Magento module working.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you need to change  **registration.php** like this

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magento_Hello',
    __DIR__
);
```

Then Delete var folder and  run  **setup:upgrade** command. Then check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
template="Magento_Hello::success.phtml"
```

Is that a valid way to define a template? In your hello_index_index.xml? I thought that was for block methods?